# Custom button in shiny

Tags: r, button, shiny

I want to build a button that changes its properties with every tap. Specifically, I want a button that start with the math symbol ">", then after you tap it changes to "<" and if you tap again it goes to '='. Is it possible to build it in Shiny?

I have built my interface like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(semantic.dashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(color = "blue",title = "Dashboard Demo", inverted = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(visible= FALSE,
                   size = 'very thin', color = "teal",
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem(tabName = "main", "Main", icon = icon("car"))    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      selected = 1,
      tabItem(
        tabName = "main",
        fluidRow(
          box(width = 7,
              title = "Produto A",
              color = "green", ribbon = TRUE, title_side = "top right",
              column(width = 7,
                     plotOutput("boxplot1")
              )
          ),
          box(width = 7,
              title = "Produto B",
              color = "red", ribbon = TRUE, title_side = "top right",
              column(width = 7,
                     plotOutput("dotplot1")
              )
          )

      )) 


  ), theme = "cerulean"

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  colscale <- c(semantic_palette[["red"]], semantic_palette[["green"]], semantic_palette[["blue"]])

  number <- reactiveVal(1)



  output$boxplot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(eval(parse(text=as.character(random[number(),1]))), axes = FALSE)
  })

  output$dotplot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(eval(parse(text=as.character(random[number(),2]))), axes = FALSE)

  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to put this button between these two boxes, in such a way that the user can compare between the photos.

Comment: I'm afraid this code isn't working for me.  What package is the function `randomize` in?  Also, when I get past that point (by creating `random` as a 2x5 matrix), I get a `figure margins too large` error.

Comment: I erased this part of the code, since it is not essential to understand my problem. There are two boxes and I want to put this '>', '<' and '=' button between them.

Answer (score 1):

I have not gone through your code deeply but tried to understand from you question

> I want a button that start with the math symbol ">", then after you
>   tap it changes to "<" and if you tap again it goes to '='. Is it
>   possible to build it in Shiny?

This following code can do it..

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard Demo"),
  dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem(tabName = "main", "Main", icon = icon("car"))
                     )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "main",
        fluidRow(
          box(width = 7,
              title = "Produto A",
              color = "green", ribbon = TRUE, title_side = "top right",
              uiOutput("action_button")
          )
        )) 
    )
  ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$action_button<-renderUI({
    actionButton("button",">")
  })

  observeEvent(input$button,{
   if(input$button==1)
   {
     updateActionButton(session,"button","<")
   }
    else if(input$button>1)
    {
      updateActionButton(session,"button","=")
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please let me know...

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much. I just made minor changes so the button could change indefinetely. Really appreciated it :)